# Is it possible to create an iOS app with only Facebook Login feature?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, facebook-login, itunes-store

I want to develop one app with only Facebook Login feature but I'm worried about Apple guideline. Is it possible to avoid app-rejection due to this?

Comment: probably not, Apple likes multiple login/signup methods and I doubt there's a good reason for restricting the login options

Comment: ya you can do it , but you can maintain the some data in your server also..

Comment: Apple allows you to use only facebook login as the only login but you have to user significant account-specific functionality. This means that you should use things from Facebook like user interest or friend list. Using the user name, profile pictures or sharing functionality are not considered account specific functionality. Apple is saying if you are not using these information then you are not supposed to use Facebook authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: **NO**

I did the same thing in one of my app. I added the Facebook login feature but did not use it for any significant feature in the app. My app was rejected. This was the not I got from Apple.

> 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected.
>
> In order to use Facebook for authentication, your app must include
>   significant account-specific functionality from Facebook. For example,
>   your app should include sufficient account-based features from
>   Facebook other than pulling profile information or sharing on the
>   user’s page.